Illegal substances make for an off topic question?
At what point did asking about particular drugs and the effect on the mind became off topic?

It never did. I closed your Q because it was self-help. You edited by adding... 

How can I do a controlled experiment or test to determine which chemical is giving me a mental advantage in creative thinking?

...and now it's OK for me. 

Thanks I saw that. I tried to write this not to infer that question. I am still interested where that line is? What did I change about it that made it on topic?

@Muze see above

I'm glad I added that.
